# Show For $U_1,U_2... \neq V:U_1 \cup U_2 \cup .........\neq V, U_1,U_2 $ Subvectorspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U_1,U_2 .. .. .. U_n $ be subvector spaces of the vector-space $V$ of the field $K$ where as $U_1,U_2 .. .. .. U_n \neq V$  and in $K$ there $\exists$ atleast $n$ elements then it is to show that:

$U_1 \cup U_2 \cup...…….  U_n \neq V$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We argue by contradiction and assume $V=\bigcup_{i=1}^n{U_i}$. We may assume that no $U_i$ is a subset of the reunion of the $U_j$, $j \neq i$.

Then, let $x \in U_1$ not in any $U_k$, $k > 1$. Let $y \notin U_1$.

Then, for all $t \in K$, $z_t=x+ty$ is in some $U_k$. Since $x$ is not in $U_k$, $k > 1$, $z_t \in U_k$ for at most one $t$. Since $y \notin U_1$, there is at most one $t$ such that $z_t \in U_1$.

Assume besides that $y \in U_l$, $l > 1$. Then if $x+ty \in U_l$, then $x \in U_l$. So each $U_k$, $k \neq l$, contains at most one $z_t$, while $U_l$ contains none. So there are at most $n-1$ distinct $z_t$. Therefore $|K| < n$, a contradiction.

Comment: you should state at the beginning that you argue by contradiction